# Does Curity Introspection supports application/token-introspection+jwt?

Tags: openid-connect, introspection, curity

Does anyone know if [Curity](https://curity.io/) supports `application/token-introspection+jwt`?

I am trying to implement https://curity.io/resources/learn/introspect-with-phantom-token/ and according to https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/api/token-introspection

*application/token-introspection+jwt* seems to be the one we should be using.

However, when I tried to use it, I am getting a HTML page with below message.

```
Provided content type not in list of allowed ones [application/json, application/jwt]
```

Answer (score 4):

The specification that introduce `application/token-introspection+jwt` is in draft state and not yet supported by Curity. Similar (more or less same) functionality can be achieved by using `Accept: application/jwt` instead.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the clarification.